# SASS Compass generates a file of 0 KB

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm a web designer and I'm developing a structured set of CSS files using SASS. I use Compass to compile my .scss files into the finale .css files.

Everything was working fine, till today when after many changes that I did, the result CSS file contained nothing. In other words, Compass successfully compiles SASS, but generates a file of 0 KB size.

Compass command line doesn't show any error.

How can I debug SASS through Compass?

Comment: Have you tried sprinkling a few `@debug` lines through your code to see if it is being processed at all?

Answer (score 1):

How are you compiling compass? Through compass app or through command line? You can set a config options in the config.rb file. You can also issue from the command line `compass compile <myProject> --debug-info` which works as well. Hope this helps!

```
sass_options = {
    :debug_info => true
}
```

Comment: Here's the same thing from the github repo [https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/552](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/552)